# TinyMCE not saving exact code in code editor

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

When I use TinyMCE, it doesn't save the exact code I put into the code editor.

For example I will have an initial value of

```
<p> Write your description here </p>
```

When I go into the code editor, and add

```
<span> Hello there </span>
```

it will switch it back to a <p> tag over the span tag. So it will be

```
<p> Hello there </p>
```

Is there any way to make sure the TinyMCE editor saves it exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow the span tag to be acceptable in your text-area, and you can add it via this `extended_valid_elements`:

```
tinymce.init({
    extended_valid_elements: 'span',
    //...other options
});
```

for more details [click here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@extended_valid_elements/)